# Get records from multiple tables, but only show 1 per ID?

Tags: mysql

First of all im sorry for the title, it's difficult to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have 2 tables, a table for property records, and a table for the images uploaded for each property.

In my `listing_details` table I enter 1 record per property that has a unique ID and property slug. I have a `prop_gallery` table where I can have hundreds of records that share the same `property slug` so I can relate it back to my my property.

I'm trying to write a query to pull the records from both tables, but I only want to show each property once, at the moment it's looping through all the records in the gallery and showing that property for as many records their are in the gallery. Hope this makes sense?

My query is...

```
$listings = $db->query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM listing_details 
    JOIN prop_gallery 
    ON prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id = listing_details.prop_slug 
    WHERE (prop_slug LIKE prop_gallery_id OR prop_gallery_id LIKE prop_slug) 
    AND listing_details.prop_mandate = 1'
)->fetchAll();
```

If there's a property called **Liams house** then there will be a record for that in `listing_details` and if I've uploaded 10 pictures, there will be 10 records for that in `prop_gallery`.

When I loop through my results this means I'm now showing **Liams house** 10 times, when I want to show it just the once.

**EDIT**

Result of the above query

```
prop_id prop_agent  prop_title            prop_slug             prop_mandate    id  prop_gallery_id prop_gallery    
37      2           House in switzerland  house-in-switzerland  1               4   6               main1.png   
37      2           House in switzerland  house-in-switzerland  1               4   6               main2.png
37      2           House in switzerland  house-in-switzerland  1               4   6               main3.png
```

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` to get a single row per property.

Comment: I've tried that @JayBlanchard as well as LIMIT 3 but still it loops through them all

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: It's not possible to give you advice unless you, at a minimum, show the names of the columns in your tables. Some sample data and a sample result will also help. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Updated question @O.Jones

Comment: Updated question @forpas

Comment: Is this your expected output or the result of your query?

Comment: No @forpas, I just want 1 record for each prop_id

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Assuming you have a [any] property in the table `listting_details` you can sort rows by you can do it cleanly; I assumed the property `recorded_at`.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    row_number() over(partition by prop_slug order by recorded_at) as rn
  FROM listing_details d
  JOIN prop_gallery g
  ON g.prop_gallery_id = l.prop_slug 
  WHERE prop_slug LIKE prop_gallery_id OR prop_gallery_id LIKE prop_slug
    AND d.prop_mandate = 1
) x
where rn = 1
```